# How to cut off part of a letter

Tags: adjustbox

I want to cut off the very top left part of an uppercase R. I tried using `\adjustbox`, but it cuts off the whole top part, which is not what I want. Here's the MWE, the corresponding output and the desired output.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\adjustbox{trim = 0pt -.5pt 0pt .5pt, clip}{R}
\end{document}
```

Corresponding output:

[image]

Desired output:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do this with `\adjustbox`, but because it can only clip rectangular areas you'll need to create two clippings and place them next to each other.

I'm using two `\adjustbox`es below: the first just shows the leftmost 0.175em of the “R”, with the top 0.1em cut off, and the second one shows the remainder of the letter.
I've `\fbox`ed the letters to show that their bounding boxes are identical and I've converted the pdf to a png with transparency to demonstrate that I'm not covering anything up :).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newcommand*\clippedR{%
  \adjustbox{viewport = {0em} {-.95em} {.175em} {\dimexpr\height-.1em}, clip,set depth=0pt}{R}%
  \adjustbox{viewport = {.175em} {-.05em} {\width} {\height}, clip,set depth=0pt}{R}%
}

\begin{document}

\fbox{R}
\fbox{\clippedR}

\end{document}
```

> [image: output]

Note that `\height`, `\width` and `\depth` can be used to refer to the original dimensions of the letter (see the [adjustbox documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/adjustbox/adjustbox.pdf)) and that `\dimexpr` can be used to perform computations with dimensions (see the [etex documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/systems/doc/etex/etex_man.pdf), §3.5 as of this writing). The `%` at the end of these lines are necessary because single newlines are normally interpreted as spaces (see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7459/156366)).

Comment: The only solution which is not a hack, +1!

Comment: The only solution that actually clips instead of covers, +1!

Comment: Nice answer! I'm just wondering if one could use a unit like `em` instead of `pt` to make it independent of the currently employed font size?

Comment: @foo You definitely can, and I probably should have. I wasn't thinking as much about creating the symbol as I was thinking about demonstrating how `\adjustbox` can be used.

Comment: @foo: Switched from `pt` to `em`, because you're right.

Answer (score 10):

What works with make-up also works for tex: instead of removing the corner of the R, cover it up:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

{    
    \leavevmode\rlap{R}\rlap{\kern-0.02em\textcolor{white}{\raisebox{0.5em}{\rule{0.2em}{0.25em}}}}
}

text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution is to simply draw over that corner using tikz:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Lengths used to hold Height/Width of `R' in current font
\newlength{\uppercaseHeight}
\newlength{\uppercaseWidth}
% R with a corner missing
\newcommand\cutR{%
% Save hieght and width of current R (depends on fontsize)
\settoheight{\uppercaseHeight}{R}%
\settowidth{\uppercaseWidth}{R}%
R% Print R
% Overlay a white rectangle
\tikz[baseline,overlay] \fill [white] % [red] % useful to use a red box when tweaking
(-\uppercaseWidth, 0.8*\uppercaseHeight) rectangle ++(0.24*\uppercaseWidth, 0.25*\uppercaseHeight);
}
\begin{document}\noindent
\small X \cutR X \\
\normalsize X \cutR X \\
\large X \cutR X
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output]

The values used in the `fill` command appear to work fairly well for the default font over a range of sizes, but you may want to adjust them to get things looking exactly as intended.

Comment: thanks. Is it possible to tweak the box so that, if I were to overlay the R with another letter, the box would only cover the R but not the other letter?

Comment: Definitely. In fact, it is very easy to modify the \cutR command to achieve this. Adding \hspace{-\uppercaseWidth}X immediately after the call to \tikz (put a % at the end of the tikz command to be sure) for example will result in an X being printed exactly on top of the cut R.

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,stackengine}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{l}{}{t}{-.1pt}{\color{white}\rule{1.8pt}{1pt}}{R}
\end{document}
```

[image]